# Approximation of a convex shape in the $d$-dimensional Euclidean space for $d\gg 1$

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, packing-and-covering

We are given a convex shape $C$ lying inside the hypercube $[0,1]^d$ in the $d$-dimensional Euclidean space. Let the volume of $C$ be $\tfrac12$ (*I guess nothing changes for any other fixed constant in $(0,1)$*).

---

**Question:** How can we prove or disprove that, for all  convex $C\subseteq [0,1]^d$ and all $d\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists a set of $n$ points lying on the boundary of $C$ where $n$ grows at most polynomially in $d$, such that the volume of their convex hull $C'$ is lower bounded by a constant independent of $d$?

---

---

***Note:*** *The main intuition underlying this conjecture is the idea that (***very***) informally, for $d\gg 1$ if there are areas where the boundary of $C$ is far from being linear (e.g., portions of $(d-1)$-balls), the volume of the regions of $C$ bounded by such areas is disregardable compared to the volume of $C$. More generally, the same holds for areas formed by $\omega(\mathrm{poly}(d))$-many linear regions that can be viewed as good approximations of manifolds with significant curvature.*

Comment: If $C$ is the cube $[0,\sqrt[d]{0.5}]^d$, what set of $n$ points can you find? I'm not seeing an obvious one.

Comment: I see the point @RavenclawPrefect , thank you! Now, thinking about the original problem I am working on from which this subproblem arose, I would like to ask the same question where $n$ can be arbitrarely large (even superpolynomial in $d$), and the conjecture is instead that the number $\phi$ of facets of $C'\subseteq C$ (in place of its number of vertices $n$) grows at most polynomially in $d$, while the volume of $C'$ is still lower bounded by a constant independent of $d$. Do you see any potential counterexample for the conjecture in this case?