# Bounding the number of facets of a polytope to approximate a given convex shape in higher dimensions

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes

We are given a convex shape $S$ lying inside the hypercube $[0,1]^d$ in the $d$-dimensional Euclidean space. Let the volume $V(S)$ of $S$ be $\tfrac12$ (*I guess nothing changes for any other fixed constant in $(0,1)$*).

---

**Question:** How can we prove or disprove that, for all $S$ and all $d\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists a set of points lying on its boundary such that their convex hull $C$ satisfy simultaneously the following properties?

- Its volume $V(C)$ is lower bounded by a constant independent of $d$.
- Its number of facets $\phi_C$ grows at most polynomially in $d$.

---

---

***Note:*** *This problem is similar to [Approximation of a convex shape in the $d$-dimensional Euclidean space for $d\gg 1$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/429558/115803), but instead of bounding the number of vertices of the approximating convex polytope lying inside the given shape, we focus on bounding the number of its facets (the motivations are given below, at the end of the following paragraph).*

*The main intuition underlying this conjecture is the idea that (***very***) informally, for $d\gg 1$ if there are areas where the boundary of $S$ is far from being linear (e.g., portions of $(d-1)$-balls), the volume of the regions of $S$ bounded by such areas is disregardable compared to the volume of $S$. More generally, the same holds for areas formed by $\omega(\mathrm{poly}(d))$-many linear regions that can be viewed as good approximations of manifolds with significant curvature (in this context, such linear regions can be viewed as facets of an approximating polytope, which is conceptually linked to bounding $\phi_C$ in this problem).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think ***if we assume the facets are simplexes***, the number of facets of such a polytope must grow more than exponentially, even in the easiest case where $S=[0,1]^d$. Fix a constant $\epsilon>0$.
Choose a finite subset of $\partial( [0,1]^d)$, spanning a polytope $C$ with $\phi_C$ facets, and volume $V(C)\ge\epsilon$. We can partition $C$ into $\phi_C$ simplexes $\{\Delta_i\}_{1\le i\le  \phi_C }$ with vertices in the center of $S$, so the volume of $C$ is not larger than $f$ times the largest volume of such simplexes. Parenthesis: the largest volume simplex included in a cube, say  $[-1,+1]^d$, and with a vertex in  the center $O$ of the cube, has wlog all its other vertices  among the vertices of the cube: for we can move any vertex $v\neq O$ in the half-space whose boundary is the hyperplane for $v$, parallel to the facet of the simplex opposite to $v$, and disjoint to it, till we reach an extremal point of the cube (a vertex of the cube), and this does not decrease the volume. Thus the maximum volume among all simplexes included in $[-1,+1]^d$ with a vertex in the origin is reached by those with $d$ vertices in $\{-1,1\}^d$ plus $0$, and it is $1/d!$ times the maximum determinant of a $\{1,-1\}$ matrix of oder $d$: this is the [Hadamard's matrix problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_maximal_determinant_problem#Hadamard%27s_bound_(for_all_n)), and the corresponding Hadamard determinant bound is $d^{d/2}$. Going back to the $\Delta_i$ and to $[0,1]^d$, and normalizing over $V([-1,+1]^d=2^d$, we conclude that $V(\Delta_i)\le   {d^{d/2}}/({2^dd!})$ for all $i$, so $V(C)\le \phi_C {d^{d/2}}/({2^dd!})$ so by Stirling formula $\phi_C\ge \frac{2^dd!}{\epsilon d^{d/2}}\sim  \sqrt{2\pi d}(4de^{-2})^{d/2} \epsilon^{-1}$ that grows more than exponentially.

Comment: Actually I think your conjecture is true e.g. for S= the cube, one can take C=S. For S = the ball, it would be difficult or impossible to find C, but the volume of a ball is o(1). So maybe for some reason, a convex $S$ in $I^d$ with $V(S)\ge1/2$, for large s, must be close to the cube itself also in shape, so that it contains a further convex with few facets and close volume.

Comment: Thank you for your answers @PietroMajer ! Do you think it always possible to partition the set of all the facets directions of any convex shape $S\subseteq [0,1]^d$ with $V(S)\ge 1/2$ in at most poly$(d)$-many subsets in such a way that all directions in each subset are (informally speaking) "very similar to each other"?

Or, in other words, whenever $S$ has $\omega(\mathrm{poly}(d))$-many facets whose directions are all dissimilar to each other (like the $2^{d-1}$ facets directions of a cross-polytope), then one can conclude that $V(S)<1/2$ (because $V(S)=o(1)$ as $d$ grows)?

Comment: Thank you, for accepting (although it’s only a very partial answer) Partitioning: Yes this sound reasonable, but maybe (e.g. in the last statement) one should only count “l a r g e facets”, that is e.g. those with $V_{d-1}>\epsilon$: otherwise S could be a polytope that looks like a cube with rounded corners, with a lot of small facets in any direction

Comment: Don't you think that what we are discussing now is very related to this question? https://mathoverflow.net/q/429726/115803 The idea underlying the question is the following:

Comment: Informally, given any (arbitrarily small) portion $B$ of the boundary of a convex shape lying in $[0,1]^d$, either it is almost flat and the total number of directions (up to a small perturbation) associated with such almost flat areas is polynomial (I actually think even linear) in $d$, or the part of the shape close to/bounded by $B$ has a disregardable volume.

Comment: For instance, if the convex shape is similar to a hypercube, it has a linear number of facets (or a linear number of facet clusters, where within each cluster, each facet direction is similar to one another), and its volume is constant. For the cross-polytope, we have a number of facets exponential in $d$ that "cannot be clustered," and its volume is disregardable. For the $d$-ball, I think we need a number of facets exponential in $d$ to approximate it with convex polytope, but such facets cannot be clustered (like for the cross-polytope case) and its volume is, again, disregardable.

Comment: Yes, it seems relevant. It would be nice to be able to argue on limits, in some convenient sense, of sequences $S_d\subset[0,1]^d$ as $d\to\infty$ . What if one includes everything in the probability product measure space $[0,1]^\mathbb N$, i.e. consider $S_d\times [0,1]^{\mathbb N + d}\subset [0,1]^\mathbb N$ ?

Comment: What geometric properties  of convex sets $S\subset [0,1]^\mathbb N$ are characteristic of those with positive measure? (E.g. the Euclidean ball, the cross-polytope , and more generally any  $\ell_p$ ball if $p<\infty$) are measure zero sets)

Comment: I believe the geometric properties that characterize such convex sets with positive measure are very related with my question mathoverflow.net/q/429726/115803 whose answer is, in my opinion, the curvature of the multidimensional generalization of the shape of this question mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/272983/74045. Informally, my conjecture is: to have positive measure, we need a very low curvature, which implies that the shape can be approximated with a hypercube. If it cannot be approximated by a hypercube, then the curvature is too high and it cannot have a positive measure.

Comment: So this goes into the geometric measure theory for convex sets, a very deep subject with a huge literature…

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139004/discussion-between-pietro-majer-and-penelope-benenati).