# Maximizing the minimum curvature of a convex shape with a given volume in higher dimensions

Tags: co.combinatorics, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry

Given any $d$-dimensional convex shape $S$ in the Euclidean space with $d\gg 1$, let $K_{\min}(S)$ be the minimum value of the Gaussian curvature of its boundary.

---

**Question:** What is the maximum value $K^*$ of $K_{\min}(S)$ over all $d$-dimensional convex shapes $S\subseteq [0,1]^d$ whose volume is greater than or equal to a constant $v$ (independent of $d$ - for instance, $v=\tfrac12$)?

Comment: For sure $K^*(d)\to 0$ as $d\to\infty$. Finding explicit bounds must be pain (if it is at all possible).